How to hide entire search results form google in the best way?
What I am trying to accomplish:
I am trying to create a google chrome extension that removes/hides certain search results from the google search results
My code thus far:
const rules = {
  "https://www.google.com/search": filterGoogleSearch,
}

const sitesToFilter = ["reddit", "wikipedia"]

function filterGoogleSearch() {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach(() => {
      const searchResults = document.querySelectorAll("#search .g")
      searchResults.forEach((result) => {
        const links = result.querySelectorAll("a")
        const cites = result.querySelectorAll("cite")

        if (shouldFilterResult(links, cites)) {
          ;(result as HTMLElement).style.display = "none"
        }
      })

      // Filter "More to ask" section
      filterMoreToAskSection()
    })
  })

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true })
  filterMoreToAskSection()
}

function filterMoreToAskSection() {
  const moreToAskSection = document.querySelector("[data-initq]")
  if (moreToAskSection) {
    const accordionItems =
      moreToAskSection.querySelectorAll('[jsname="yEVEwb"]')
    accordionItems.forEach((item) => {
      const links = item.querySelectorAll("a")
      const cites = item.querySelectorAll("cite")

      if (shouldFilterResult(links, cites)) {
        ;(item as HTMLElement).style.display = "none"
      }
    })
  }
}

function shouldFilterResult(
  links: NodeListOf<HTMLAnchorElement>,
  cites: NodeListOf<HTMLElement>
): boolean {
  for (const link of links) {
    if (shouldFilterLink(link.href)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  for (const cite of cites) {
    if (shouldFilterLink(cite.textContent)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

function shouldFilterLink(url: string): boolean {
  if (!url) return false

  try {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(url)
    const hostname = parsedUrl.hostname

    for (const site of sitesToFilter) {
      if (hostname.includes(site)) {
        console.log(`Filtered: ${url} (matched: ${site})`)
        return true
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Invalid URL: ${url}`)
  }
  return false
}

// Check if the current URL starts with any of the keys in rules
for (const url in rules) {
  if (document.URL.startsWith(url)) {
    rules[url]()
    break
  }
}

What I think I am doing wrong (but not sure how to fix it):
Selecting which element to hide can be done in a safer way so i dont need to alter my code everytime google changes its page slightly
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It would help tremendously if you could state a concrete problem. You cannot solve the point that google uses generic classes in their search results, you cannot query for something else IMHO because the generic class is the only distinguishing thing from the rest of google's <div>-soup and that a page possibly looks broken when you remove elements from it is to be expected. EDIT Instead of looking for a class you could traverse the DOM tree by elements, but thats as likely to change as the generic class and has - TBH - more possible problems.

Thanks for your insight @Davi !I actually changed my code to set the display setting of the HTMLElement to "none" instead of removing the entire div. This fixed the issue of the page being broken.
Also instead of searching for a specific div I am now querying for ("#search .g") which returns better results for now but still has the opporunity to change
